# How can I restrict a textbox to take only one predefined string and throw an message box in else case

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, messagebox

In my winform application I have a textbox that should only take a predefined local server address and throws an message box in the else case as soon as the focus changes from that textbox

Comment: If you already know what the answer should be, why are you using a text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event. This event will fire when the control should be validated, which by default happens when the control loses focus.